# Position:absolute; not working

Tags: html, css

I'm pretty clueless on what the problem might be, but what works fine [here](http://robus.info/map/) does not [here](http://seaconflict.com/archipelago/) (login with 123/123)

CSS:

```
#drag {
    width: 700px; 
    height: 400px; 
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative; 
}



.inside {
    width: 500px; 
    height: 500px;
}
.drag {
    width: 700px;
    height: 400px;
    background: #333 url('bg.png'); 
}
```

I've tried to remove the .inside class, and also messed with the html a bit (re-checked the pos:relative part a million times)... with no results. Any idea?

[edit]

@Marcel Korpel : On the second one all islands end up in the upper left corner, despite having pos:absolute, top:x and left:x set

Comment: Your website is redirecting me indefinitely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used FireBug and it says that the #nr0, #nr1, ... divs just have a `position:absolute;`, but no `left` or `top` attribute

Comment: Uh. They do if you look in the HTML: `<div style='position:absolute; top:77; left:41;' id='nr1'><img src='/media/island.png'></div>`

Comment: Validate. Validate. Validate. Your CSS has machine detectable errors.

Comment: you have to add a 'px' to 77 or 41, like '77px', else it won't work!

Comment: Uhh silly me. Now I feel ashamed for even asking. Nevertheless, thanks alot!